# EasyUI: draggable() doesn't initialize when being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to call EasyUI's `draggable` everytime I dynamically create new HTML elements. I have the `draggable` method enclosed like so:

```
function initializedrag() {
    console.log("initializedrag called")
    $(".item").draggable({
        revert:true,
        proxy:'clone',
        onStartDrag:function(){
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = "not-allowed";
            $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',3);
        },
        onStopDrag:function(){
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor="move";
        }
    });
    console.log("end of initializedrag")
}
```

And I use `load` to load in a new html site that contains a div with some `li` items and `a` tags that have a class of `.item`, like so, when the page is ready:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("ready");
    $("#shop").load("shopcontent/cat1.html");
    initializedrag();

    ...
});
```

Through the console.logs, it's calling the function fine, however, the drag functionality isn't actually working. The exact same `draggable` works when I have a element that is already on the page, and `draggable` on page load. However, I need it to work whenever I call the `initializedrag` function.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED! 
It was quite simple really, I just enclosed the initializedrag() in a function that gets called when the content is loaded! 
So instead of:

```
$("#shop").load("shopcontent/cat1.html");
initializedrag();
```

I did:

```
$("#shop").load("shopcontent/cat1.html", function() {
    initializedrag();
});
```

Which is odd because I put the contents of initializedrag() in a function just like above yesterday, but it didn't work :)